# How to get total working duration in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, time-tracking

I have a table like below in oracle 11g

```
ACT_DTL_ID  USER_ID   ACTIVITY_TYPE   ACTIVITY_TIME
0000000003  DOC000035   LOGIN           03-07-17 12:35:39.000000000 PM
0000000004  DOC000035   LOGOUT          03-07-17 12:41:07.000000000 PM
0000000005  DOC000035   LOGIN           03-07-17 12:41:28.000000000 PM
0000000006  DOC000035   LOGOUT          03-07-17 12:50:35.000000000 PM
```

I want to calculate total working duration for the user.

Can you please help me?

Comment: I helped formatting. You probably need to do a sum on the differences between *consecutive* LOGIN and LOGOUTs... Now show us what you tried and we'll help more! Read [ask] in case...

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  sum((x.activity_time - to_date('01.01.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY') * decode(x.activity_type,'LOGIN',-1,1))
from
  your_table x
;
```

though this only works if the list starts with a Login and ends with a Logout.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to get logout time immediate after login. There can be multiple login and logout in a day.

Comment: did you even try it?